# Where should sys.path.append('...') statement go?

Tags: python, coding-style

Just after standard pythonmodule imports?
If I postpone it to the main function and do my specific module imports before it, it gives error (which is quite obvious). Python Style guide no where mentions the correct location for it.

Answer (score 8):

It should go before the `import` or `from` statements that need it (which as you say is obvious).  So for example a module could start with:

```
import sys
import os
import math
try:
  import foo
except ImportError:
  if 'foopath' in sys.path: raise
  sys.path.append('foopath')
  import foo
```

Note that I've made the append conditional (on the import failing *and* the specific module's path not being on `sys.path` yet) to avoid the risk of `sys.path` ending up with dozens of occurrences of string `foopath`, which would not be particularly helpful;-).

Answer (score 4):

One reason this isn't mentioned in PEP 8 or other good Python style guides is that modifying `sys.path` *isn't something you want to do in a real program*; it makes your program less robust and portable. A better solution might be to put your package somewhere that would already be in `sys.path` or to define `PYTHONPATH` systemwide to include your package.

Answer (score 1):

I often use a shell script to launch my python applications: I put my `sys.path.insert` (`append`) statement just after the "standard" python module imports in my "launch python script".

Using `sys.path.insert(0, ...)` gets your "imports" in priority in the path list.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do it before importing anything. If you're worried that your module names might conflict with the Python stdlib names, then change your module names!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of taste. But most people tend to put it behind the `import sys` :-)
I prefer wrapping it in an extra function:

```
def importmod_abs(name):
   sys.path.append() ..

   __import__ ...

   sys.path.pop()
```

... this way `sys.path` remains clean. Of course that's only applicable to certain module structures. Anyways, I'd import everything that works without altering `sys.path` first.